# Temporal Tables and Log shipping

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, temporal-tables

We are building a system in our company which will need temporal tables in sql server and might need log shipping as well. I wanted to know if there are any unexpected impacts of log shipping on a temporal table that wouldn't happen on a normal table?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect no impact in either direction (that is, log song won't change the temporal table nor will the temporal table change log shipping). At its core, log shipping is just restoring transaction logs on another server. And temporal tables are (more or less) a trigger that maintains another table on data mutations. That extra work will be present in the log backup and will restore just fine at the log shipping secondary

Answer (score 0):

Previously in the company we used temporary tables, but when the volume of business data had to grow, we had to change the queries using WITH

```
WITH table_alias AS (SELECT ...)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017) <> [temporary tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables).